# How to insert a values into different table in a single php page?

Tags: php, mysql

I am inserting a record on my table after inserting to another table. This my sample code:

```php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $database = new Database();
    $db = $database->getConnection();
    $employee = new Employee($db);

    if(!empty($first_name) && !empty($family_name) && !empty($first_name_arabic) && !empty($family_name_arabic)){
        $emp_number = isset($_POST['emp_number']) && !empty($_POST['emp_number']) ? $_POST['emp_number'] : $employee->generateEmployeeNumber();
        $fields = [
            'reference' => $reference,
            'emp_number' => $emp_number,
            'first_name' => $first_name,
            'middle_name' => $middle_name,
            'third_name' => $third_name,
            'family_name' => $family_name,
            'nationality' => $nationality,
        ];

        $employee->createOrUpdate($fields, '');
        $result = $employee->selectOne('Reference', $reference);

        if(!empty($_POST['passport_number']) && !empty($_POST['passport_place_issue']) && !empty($_POST['passport_date_issue']) && !empty($_POST['passport_date_expiry']) && !empty($result['id'])) {
            $passport = new Passport($db);

            $passport_fields = [
                'passport_number' => $_POST['passport_number'],
                'place_issue' => $_POST['passport_place_issue'],
                'date_issue' => date_format(date_create($_POST['passport_date_issue']), 'Y-m-d'),
                'date_expiry' => date_format(date_create($_POST['passport_date_expiry']), 'Y-m-d'),
                'reference' => $result['reference'] ,
                'employee_id' => $result['id'],
                'status' => 'Active',
            ];
            $passport->createOrUpdate($passport_fields, '');
        }
    }
}
```

but my problem is my insertion for `passport` table is not doing anything and no error is being return to me. As for the `creatOrUpdate` this is how i did:

```php
function createOrUpdate($fields, $id){
    if(is_null($id) || empty($id)){
        $implodeColumns = implode(', ', array_keys($fields));
        $implodePlaceholder = implode(", :", array_keys($fields));

        $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $this->table_name. "($implodeColumns) VALUES(:".$implodePlaceholder.")";
        echo "SQL ".$sql;
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
            $stmt->bindValue(":".$key,$value);
        }
        $stmt->execute();
    }else{}
}
```

I don't know if creating a method with a same name is affecting the code, but `createOeUpdate` method for employee is from `employee.php` where `createOrUpdate` mehod for passport is from `passport.php`. Only employee is being saved in my database.

**Any help is much appreciated**

Answer (score 0):

If the names are the same from different files you need to use namespaces like:

```
namespace name_of_your_main_file;

// Maybe need to add full path 
// if it's not in the same folder.

use employee; 
use passport; 

// And use it with same names as:
employee::createOrUpdate(
```

Comment: What is the right way to point to my file? I have this on top of my file: ```include_once '../../api/models/passport.php';```